# IE6 targetting, * or _ better?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I need to target IE6 only to fix a bug. I know conditional style sheets would be better but I only have access to the CSS not HTML (long story).

It seems like I can achieve this with either of the following:

```
*html .mydiv {
    height: 40px;
}

.mydiv {
    _height: 40px;
}
```

Is one solution better than the other?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option, `_height: 40px;` is unrecommended, as it doesn't validate properly against W3C standards. You can read more about IE6 hacks here: http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks#in_css.

As far as I am aware, both should be applied to only IE6 and below.

Regardless of this, the choice would depend on the context. The former would be better for a group of fixes for IE6, and the latter for a single property in an already existing group.

Answer (score 1):

Not really better, but the 2nd one doesn't require a separate selector. This will make the css more readable and also saves a view bytes.

```
.mydiv {
    height: 38px;    
    _height: 40px;
}
```

For trained eyes it's clear, that's a IE6 hack.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are hacks that exploit bugs in the browser, so they are equally bad to use. I you have access to the server, it would be slightly better to serve different stylesheets depending on the user agent string of the browser.

If I had to use one of them I would prefer the first one (the one that exploits the selector bug) since it is obvious early in the paragraph that it is IE specific (in the second case you need to read longer to see it). None of them should be used without a clear comment.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful:
_ is ie6 only,
* is both for ie6 and ie7.

You might also consider this type of css forking, which results a cleaner code:

```
<!--[if le IE 6]>
<link rel...>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: The OP stated he cannot edit the HTML and therefore cannot use a conditional style-sheet.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. (Anyway, its good to have both solution in mind - and keep those snippets together -, so i just keep it unedited.)